# Can I export related fields using a data loader?

Tags: data-loader, relationships, data-export

I want to be able to export the related account fields for each quotation in Salesforce using Data Loader. I suspect this is possible using relationships (Object__r.FieldName__c), but I'm not 100% sure. If it is possible, can you explain how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can export parent and their parent attribute values from Child object.

But from the parent, you cannot export child object related attributes.

You could move to 5 levels up to the Parent or related objects.

> **As we cannot query foreign key relationships more than 5 levels away from the root SObject**

so, maximum up to this level is supported from Quote:

> Opportunity.Account.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name

In the below example I have shown how to move from

> Quote --> Opportunity --> Parent Account --> Parent.Parent.Account

**Example**

```
SELECT Id, Name, 
    OpportunityId, 
    Opportunity.Name, 
    Opportunity.Account.Name, 
    Opportunity.Account.Id, 
    Opportunity.Account.ParentId, 
    Opportunity.Account.Parent.Name
FROM Quote
```

**Results**

[image: hierarchy]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Data Loader supports this behavior. You just have to type out your `SELECT` clause, since it won't let you select them yourself. For example, this query exports just fine:

```
SELECT Profile.Name FROM User
```

You can use any `Parent__r.Field__c` you want, you just have to properly specify the field path.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. Say for example if Account is a Parent object and User id is a child object. Then you can export the data of the user object by a query into the Account object. You have to use a relationship query like below:

```
SELECT ACCOUNTOWNER,CLIENT_PARTNER__r.name,CLIENT_PARTNER__r.email from ACCOUNT
```

Here CLIENT_PARTNER__c is the API name on account object.